# Vector of ints on heap and freeing memory

Tags: c++, memory, vector, free

I'm creating a vector of ints on the heap like this:

`std::vector<int> vec = *new std::vector<int>();`

then I get to the end of my program and I need to free the memory, but using `vec.clear()` doesn't free the memory.

How do I do this properly?

Thanks and all the best
-Mitchell

Comment: `*new` Uh, why are you doing this?

Comment: For every new you want a delete, so delete vec.

Comment: @brianbeuning: `vec` is not a pointer and was not `new`'d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I do this properly?

Replace this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = *new std::vector<int>();
```

With this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
```

Problem solved.

Unlike other languages you may have come across, `new` is best avoided in most situations.  It dynamically allocates objects, like in other languages.  But unlike other languages, C++ doesn't have a garbage collector, so you need to manually destroy objects that you dynamically allocate.  However, the way you've written your code, you've made that impossible.

You're dynamically allocating an object with new, which returns a pointer to the object.  Then you are dereferencing that pointer (via *), and copying the object to `vec`.  `vec` gets properly destroyed, but the dynamically allocated object that it was copied from does not.  And since you didn't store that pointer, you're left with no way to access that object, and no way to dispose of it. In order to destroy that object, you would have had to capture the pointer, like this:

```
std::vector<int>* vec_pointer = new std::vector<int>();
```

Then later, you could call delete on the pointer, which destroys the object and deallocates the memory:

```
delete vec_pointer;
```

Thankfully, dynamic allocation is not a necessity as it often is in those other languages.  Declaring an object creates it, and it is destroyed when it goes out of scope.  So the simple line of code I showed you is sufficient, with no delete statement necessary.

As a side note, if you've determined, for some reason, that you must have dynamic allocation.  Use a smart pointer (google that).

Comment: That was perfect, can you also explain why what I did was wrong?

Comment: @Mitchell: You dynamically allocated a vector, dereferenced that pointer value, copied it to `vec`, then lost any reference to the allocated memory so leaked.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is leaking memory.

`std::vector<int> vec` declares a vector on the stack. You create a second (empty) vector on the heap, and use it to copy-construct the one on the stack. Since it's empty, this effectively does nothing.

But, you've lost the pointer to the vector that was created on the heap (because you never stored it). So you can't delete it, and that memory can't be reclaimed. The vector on the stack, however, cleans up after itself just fine.

What you probably want is just:

```
std::vector<int> vec;    // Vector on stack, no manual memory management required
```

If you really want to use the heap for some reason (the stack is faster, and vector object itself is of a small fixed size regardless of how many elements you put in it, so you don't have to worry about overflowing the stack), you can do:

```
// Declare pointer to vector, and initialize it with a new vector on the heap
std::vector<int>* vec = new std::vector<int>();
```

Or even (in C++11):

```
auto vec = new std::vector<int>();
```

Then, when you are done with it:

```
delete vec;
```